# Does the payload 4096 bytes include the registration_id length?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

In the Android GCM document, it is said that the payload is up to 4096 bytes limit.

Does the payload's 4096 bytes include the registration_id length? I found I could send a message with a payload of 16038 bytes (including the registration_ids).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't include the registration ids.

I'm sorry for not supplying any supporting documentation. The GCM documentation doesn't state it clearly. However, I tested it in order to verify this behavior.
The only "proof" I can supply is that in a multicast message you can include up to 1000 registration ids. A 1000 registration ids obviously cannot fit into the 4096 bytes of the payload.

From http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html :

> registration_ids
>
> A string array with the list of devices (registration IDs) receiving the message. It must contain at least 1 and at most 1000 registration IDs. To send a multicast message, you must use JSON. For sending a single message to a single device, you could use a JSON object with just 1 registration id, or plain text (see below). Required.

Comment: .i am not sure. does google will not count the registration_id int the payload out.no document refered.in gcm case i find the message with payload like fellow:{
  "registration_id" : "APA91bHun4MxP5egoKMwt2KZFBaFUH-1RYqx...",
  "data" : {
    "Nick" : "Mario",
    "Text" : "great match!",
    "Room" : "PortugalVSDenmark",
  },
}

Comment: In the example you supplied, the payload length is 4+5+4+12+4+16 (the lengths of the field names and values). You can verify it yourself by trying to substitute them with a single key/value pair where the length of the key + the length of the value = 4096. You'll see that the message will be sent. Then you can add a single character and see that the message will be rejected. The only disclaimer I have to mention is that I only tested it for the simple format, not the JSON, but I expect them to behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the accepted answer. I have been testing this and the result is as follows:

The max lenght of the payload is 4096 bytes. If you are using JSON, and your message is as follows:

```
{
  "to" : "APA91bGbkLeRLD228BKYQy4syvAYd5ErYiHup5FzofY_8x5CNHmhMlB65CaCHj9ntm7zcMhzDEkd9vi6rxM89cRzPuDLPrlX8UgYExGQ3LmakGTKpkIS0CE9-9tinlIRLMiLoGKDn5jVvks0njvcGFPJSHBn23cd-A",
  "data": {"a":"Some information. Only this part inside data counts as payload"}
}
```

The only part of the message that counts as payload is the part inside "data". This is true even if you are sending to multiple devices.

```
{
  "registration_ids" : ["APA91bGbkLeRLD228BKYQy4syvAYd5ErYiHup5FzofY_8x5CNHmhMlB65CaCHj9ntm7zcMhzDEkd9vi6rxM89cRzPuDLPrlX8UgYExGQ3LmakGTKpkIS0CE9-9tinlIRLMiLoGKDn5jVvks0njvcGFPJSHBn23cd-A",
                        "APA91bGbkLeRLD228BKYQy4syvAYd5ErYiHup5FzofY_8x5CNHmhMlB65CaCHj9ntm7zcMhzDEkd9vi6rxM89cRzPuDLPrlX8UgYExGQ3LmakGTKpkIS0CE9-9tinlIRLMiLoGKDn5jVvks0njvcGFPJSHBn23cd-A"]
  "data": {"a":"Some information. Only this part inside data counts as payload"}
}
```